# How to install Etherpad Lite on a subdirectory in my webspace?

Tags: apache, installation, etherpad

Hello after reading a lot of documentations,
I couldn't figured out how to install properly Etherpad lite in my webspace so it is accessible at the address "http://www.domain.com/etherpad/"

My webserver is Apache, and my database is MySQL, I have Wordpress currently running well.

I created a specific database, but I am not sure how to config Etherpad correctly. Can someone explain me which is the procedure?

I assume that I should upload Etherpad Lite's files in the directory and I should change the seetings in settings.json, but other than that? What else needs to be done?

FYI I am trying to use participad, a plugin of Wordpress which use Etherpad, but without installation of etherpad it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually pretty easy. Configure Etherpad to listen on 127.0.0.1 (localhost only) and whatever port you like, create the `etherpad` sub directory and put the following `.htaccess` file there:

```
DirectoryIndex ""
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) http://localhost:9001/$1 [P]
```

`DirectoryIndex ""` is necessary because Apache would otherwise try to fetch the index.html file.

I am not sure if this is a good solution, but it seems to work fine.

Furthermore, do **not** put Etherpad inside the webserver directory or anyone would be able to access your passwords (they are stored as plain text in the settings.json). Just put it somewhere private and start it by running `bin/run.sh` inside it's directory.